# advanced nginx http to https redirect on custom and different ports

Tags: nginx, redirect, http-redirect

I have a the following nginx configuration file where i want to redirect all http to https but with different `server_name` and custom ports

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.abc.example.com abc.example.com abc.example.local:123;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name *.abc.example.com abc.example.com abc.example.local:456;

}
```

this is a bit different because of the non-custom ports for the other `server_name` ===> `abc.example.local:123` on http that need to redirect to `abc.example.local:456` on https

What will be best way to approach this special case so that it properly redirects all http to https regardless of server_name and if it has different ports for http and https or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`server_name` can't have a port - only `listen` can specify a port.

If you want `abc.example.local` to listen on port 123 - you will need a separate server block for it. And then another server block which will listen on port 456.

Comment: Moreover, while the [`Host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) HTTP header can contain the port part, nginx does not expect those part to be specified among the server name, and from two server blocks `server { listen 123; server_name example.com:123; ... }` and `server { listen 123; server_name example.com; ... }` it is the second one that will be chosen to handle the request even if the `Host` header value will be equal to `example.com:123`.

Comment: actually you are right, ports not belong in server_name, i look stupid now...thanks